# I want to do clipping Object at WebGL

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

can I clipping object in WebGl?

it's possible to OpenGL but.. how about WebGL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not webgl, but it has what you need to know 
http://github.prideout.net/clip-planes/
http://glbook.gamedev.net/GLBOOK/glbook.gamedev.net/moglgp/advclip.html